# How do I socket.emit() data that is coming from a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

Node.js - Socket.io

I can pass data from the server to the client just fine if that's a string or a hard-coded variable:

```
var greeting = 'hello';
socket.emit('greeting', greeting);
```

But when the data comes from a function, that doesn't work anymore:

```
function search() {
 var greeting = 'hello';
}
search();
socket.emit('greeting', greeting);
```

**Edit:**
Let me share more code: (Please note that console.log of results works, shows the JSON data, but emit shows null).

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('user location', function(content) {
    fetch();
    socket.emit('results', fetch());
  });
});

function fetch() {
  yelp.search({term: "food", location: location, limit: 1}, function(error, data) {
    var results = data.businesses;
    console.log(results); // THIS WORKS
    return results;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:-

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('user location', function(content) {
    fetch(function(data){
        socket.emit('results', data);
    });
  });
});

function fetch(callback) {
  yelp.search({term: "food", location: location, limit: 1}, function(error, data) {
    var results = data.businesses;
    console.log(results); // THIS WORKS
    callback(results);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your variable is not defined outside the function.

This should work:

```
var greeting;

function search() {
    greeting = 'hello';
}
search();
socket.emit('greeting', greeting);
```

Or you use a return value of your function, which is a little more elegant:

```
function search() {
    var greeting = 'hello';

    return greeting;
}

socket.emit('greeting', search());
```

For further reading about variable scope I can recommend the ["You don't know JS" series](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/README.md).